# How do I correctly use MySQLI query and fetch?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I just started learning PHP and was following an old guide to make something that I was interested in. The entire guide was using the old deprecated mysql functions, so I decided to venture out of my small experience in PHP and try fixing everything myself. I decided to migrate to mysqli as it seemed as an easier alternative compared to PDO. Everything seemed to work well, until I realized that my user log-in wasn't quite working. Here is how I have it setup:

```
$password = md5($_POST['user_password']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE user_email = '$user_email' 
        AND user_password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($link->query($sql));

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $result['user_id'];
$_SESSION['user_acl_id'] = $result['user_acl_control_id'];
$_SESSION['user_first_name'] = $result['user_first_name'];
$_SESSION['user_last_name'] = $result['user_last_name'];`
```

Whenever I try to enter the password through the login, it tells me I am wrong even though it is correct. I suspect my issue is within this line:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($link->query($sql));
```

The guide originally had it like this:

```
$password = md5($_POST['user_password']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '$user_email' AND user_password = '$password'";
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $result['user_id'];
$_SESSION['user_acl_id'] = $result['user_acl_control_id'];
$_SESSION['user_first_name'] = $result['user_first_name'];
$_SESSION['user_last_name'] = $result['user_last_name'];
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me out! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it this way

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
```

Replace `$con` with your connection name

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm!

Comment: what does it show now?try `echo $result['user_id'];` after that line

Comment: @user405892 Welcome :)